# Multiplication over an elliptic curve using the monero cryptographic libraries

Tags: elliptic-curve

I am trying to implement a PoC of some variant of monero.
Currently for start, I want to generate the expression `G*a*i^2` given all the scalars `(a,i,2)`.

I've lost my way while looking at Monero libraries since the structs and the names of the functions and their inputs/outputs are not clear and well documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming G is the base point and i is a scalar (the convention is to write points in capital letters and scalars in lowercase letters):

`rct::key tmp;
  sc_mul(i.bytes, i.bytes, i.bytes); // i = i^2
  sc_mul(tmp.bytes, a.bytes, i.bytes); // tmp = a * i^2
  rct::scalarmultBase(tmp, tmp); // tmp = a * i^2 * G`

The rct API is easier to use than the fe/ge API, but it has a single type for points and scalars, which make it more error prone. sc_mul (scalar multiplication) is the fe API, and scalarmultBase is the rct API.

Comment: Btw fe (field elements) and scalars are slightly different things. Field elements are in the range of the size of the prime finite field which is of size q (2^255-19), and scalars are in the range of the prime group size of the base point G (2^252+....).

Comment: Ok, got it. One more related question, lets say I want an exponent bigger than 2 (for i), say `i^30` ; is there an efficient way to do it? (the naive way of doing it in an iterative manner seems really inefficient).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Efficient_computation_with_integer_exponents

Comment: I assume that `i` is of type `key`, while also temp. Though, temp is a point on the curve and `i` is a scalar. How is it possible?

Comment: Yes. As I said in the anwer, "a single type for points and scalars". You don't have to use it for the fe/ge API though, there are other types such as ge_p3 for points.